# How do I make text-decoration underline extend for the maximum width of the page?

Tags: html, css

How do I make text-decoration underline extend for the maximum width of the page?

Normally it only extends as far as the word, but I would like the line to fill the whole page.

I tried using a border line instead of text-decoration, but that causes the line to go too far below the word.

```
    example:
    .word {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    <p class="word">EXAMPLE</p>
```

Now the underline only extends as far as the word EXAMPLE.
How do I get the line to extend to the width of the entire page?

Comment: can you show what you want?

Comment: Daniel, look at it now.

Answer (score 4):

use `::before` pseudo element and generated `content` like this

```css
.word {}
.word::before {
  content:" ";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom:1px solid red; /*use this to adjust underlin color and size*/
  width:100%;  /*use this to adjust underline width*/
  height:1.1em; /*use this to adjust underline position*/
}
```

```html
<p class="word">EXAMPLE</p>
```

with `::before` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before ) you basically create a new element "on the fly" as first child in your `.word` `p` tag then you use this new element to render your underline

Comment: Why do you have to include :before?

Comment: ::before create the element where we apply the border style to simulate the underline, advantage is that we control control position, size and appearance of said underline

Answer (score 2):

You can't extend the underline like that with CSS. The closest thing would be to put the text in an element that is the full width of the page, then use a `border-bottom`. You can adjust how close the border is to the text with `padding-bottom` and/or `line-height`.

```css
.word {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 13px;
 }
```

```html
   <p class="word">EXAMPLE</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

make a `border-bottom` for the `<p>` tag and reduce the `line-height` till it became close enough to the word as the following:

```
p {
   border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
   font-size:14px;
   line-height:12px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background-image (or gradient).

```css
.word {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 1em, black 1em, black 1.1em, transparent 1.1em ,transparent 1.2em)  0 0.1em;/* color black can be reset to any other */
  background-size:auto 1.2em;/* set this according to line-height set */
}
```

```html
<h1 class="word">title</h1>
<h2 class="word">title</h2>
<h3 class="word">title</h3>
<h4 class="word">title</h4>
<h5 class="word">title</h5>
<h6 class="word">title</h6>
<p class="word">EXAMPLE</p>
<p class="word">two<br/> lines</p>
```